# Project Euler #45 - Triangular, pentagonal, and hexagonal

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

[Project Euler Problem 45](https://projecteuler.net/problem=45)

> Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the
>   following formulae:
>
> Triangle      Tn=n(n+1)/2     1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ... Pentagonal 
>     Pn=n(3n−1)/2        1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ... Hexagonal     Hn=n(2n−1)      1, 6,
>   15, 28, 45, ... It can be verified that T285 = P165 = H143 = 40755.
>
> Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.

**My Implementation:**

I used a HashSet for fast searching. I got the right answer after experimenting with the size of the HashSet. 100000 worked for me.

```
void Main()
{
    var pen = Pentagonals(100000);
    var hex = Hexagonals(100000);

    foreach(var n in Triangles()){
        if(pen.Contains(n) && hex.Contains(n) && n > 40755){
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            return;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<BigInteger> Triangles()
{
    for(BigInteger n = 1;;n++)
    {
        yield return (n * (n + 1) / 2); 
    }
}

HashSet<BigInteger> Pentagonals(int limit)
{
    HashSet<BigInteger> set = new HashSet<BigInteger>();
    for(BigInteger n = 1;n <= limit;n++)
    {
        set.Add(n * (3 *n - 1) / 2); 
    }
    return set;
}

HashSet<BigInteger> Hexagonals(int limit)
{
    HashSet<BigInteger> set = new HashSet<BigInteger>();
    for(BigInteger n = 1;n <= limit;n++)
    {
        set.Add(n * (2*n - 1)); 
    }
    return set;
}
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 4):

This expands my comments on [Brythan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53820/brythan)'s answer:

*Note: It's written in JavaScript (not C#) since I haven't written C# in years but you should be able to convert it fairly easily.*

**Answer 1 - Test if successive hexagonal numbers are also triangular and pentagonal**

A number \$c\$ is triangular if \$c = t(t + 1)/2\$ (where \$c \in \mathbb{N}\$ and \$t \in \mathbb{N}\$) which can be rewritten as \$0 = t^2 + t -2c\$ and then in terms on \$t\$, using the positive root given by the quadratic formula, as \$t = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8c}}{2}\$.

Similarly, the pentagonal number formula \$c = p(3p-1)/2\$ (where \$c \in \mathbb{N}\$ and \$p \in \mathbb{N}\$) can be rewritten as \$0 = 3p^2 - p - 2c\$ then as \$p = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+24c}}{6}\$ .

You can then use these to test successive hexagonal numbers to see if the they are also triangular and pentagonal:

```
function quadraticRoot(a,b,c){
  return ( -b + Math.sqrt( b*b - 4 * a * c ) ) / (2 * a);
}

function isInteger(n){
  return n === Math.round( n );
}

function isTriangularNumber(n){
  return isInteger( quadraticRoot( 1, 1, n*-2) );
}

function isPentagonalNumber(n){
  return isInteger( quadraticRoot( 3,-1, n*-2 ) );
}

function getNextHexagonalNumberWhichIsTriangularAndPentagonal(n){
  var hex;
  while( true ) {
    hex = n * ( 2 * n - 1 );
    if ( isTriangularNumber( hex ) && isPentagonalNumber( hex ) )
    {
      return n;
    }
    ++n;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
getNextHexagonalNumberWhichIsTriangularAndPentagonal( 144 );
```

Gives the answer `27693` as the next hexagonal number that is also triangular and pentagonal.

**Answer 2 - Generate successive triangular, pentagonal and hexagonal numbers**

```
function getTriangular(n){
  return n * (n + 1 ) / 2;
}

function getPentagonal(n){
  return n * ( 3 * n - 1 ) / 2;
}

function getHexagonal(n){
  return n * ( 2 * n - 1 );
}

function getNextEqualTriangluarPentagonalHexagonalNumbers(t,p,h){
  var tt = getTriangular(t);
  var pp = getPentagonal(p);
  var hh = getHexagonal(h);
  while ( true ){
    var max = Math.max( tt, pp, hh );
    if ( tt < max ) {
      tt = getTriangular(++t);
    } else if ( pp < max ) {
      pp = getPentagonal(++p);
    } else if ( hh < max ) {
      hh = getHexagonal(++h);
    } else {
      return [t,p,h];
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
getNextEqualTriangluarPentagonalHexagonalNumbers(286,166,144);
```

Gives the answer `[ 55385, 31977, 27693 ]` for the next triangular, pentagonal and hexagonal numbers which are identical.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var n in Triangles()){
```

You shouldn't call this variable `n`.  Elsewhere, you use `n` to mean the number that you use to generate the other numbers.  You shouldn't also use it for the result.  I'd name it either `x` (standard for an unknown value) or `candidate` (each value that you check is a candidate for being the one that you want).

```
for(BigInteger n = 1;;n++)
```

You don't need to start with `1` here.  You could start with `n = 286`, as that is the next triangular number after 40,755.  That will also save you having to check `n > 40755` in `main`.  You could also do the same thing with the pentagonals and hexagonals.  However, we can do better than this in terms of memory.

It's possible to test directly if a number is [triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) or [pentagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number#The_perfect_square_test).  So all you have to do to solve this is to generate all the hexagonal numbers starting with the 144th (the next hexagonal number after 40,755), and then test if they are triangular and pentagonal.  This saves the memory to store the two HashSets.

Both these solutions should be about the same in how they grow in computation time.  Your algorithm may be faster in absolute terms, as the tests are more expensive than the generation.  This algorithm is better in that it only generates numbers up to the solution and doesn't require a large amount of memory.  Your algorithm will run out of memory first.  It's unclear if both will be computationally intractable before that happens.

If your algorithm is significantly faster, you can also adjust it to not require the `HashSet` storage.  You can generate the pentagonals and hexagonals as you need them, saving only the largest.  This is because all three sequences are strictly increasing.  So once your largest triangular number is greater than your current pentagonal or hexagonal, you can forget the current one and move to the next.

I'd write some code, but I'm not really familiar with C#.  Hopefully I've described the algorithms well enough that you can write the necessary code.

Comment: I don't know C# either but as JavaScript: `var root = function(a,b,c){ return ( -b + Math.sqrt( b*b - 4 * a * c ) ) / (2 * a); };
var isInteger  = function(n){ return n === Math.round( n ); }
var isTriangle = function(n){ return isInteger( root(1,1,n*-2) ); };
var isPentagonal = function(n){ return isInteger( root( 3,-1,n*-2 ) ); };
var getNextTriangularPentagonalHexagonalNumber = function(n){
  var hex;
  while( true ) {
    hex = n * ( 2 * n - 1 );
    if ( isTriangle( hex ) && isPentagonal( hex ) )
      return n;
    ++n;
  }
}
getNextTriangularPentagonalHexagonalNumber( 144 );`

Comment: Or `var getTriangular = function(n){ return n * (n + 1 ) / 2; }, getPentagonal = function(n){ return n * ( 3 * n - 1 ) / 2; }, getHexagonal  = function(n){ return n * ( 2 * n - 1 ); }, getNextTriangluarPentagonalHexagonalNumber = function(t,p,h){
var tt = getTriangular(t), pp = getPentagonal(p), hh  = getHexagonal(h);
while ( true ){ var max = Math.max( tt, pp, hh );
if ( tt < max )
{
tt = getTriangular(++t);
}
else if ( pp < max )
{
pp = getPentagonal(++p);
}
else if ( hh < max )
{
hh = getHexagonal(++h);
}
else
{
return [t,p,h];
}
}
}
getNextTriangluarPentagonalHexagonalNumber(286,166,144);`

Comment: @MT0  Those would be much easier to read in an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

- The first thing you have to realize is that every hexagonal number is also a triangular number, so you don't have to check triangular numbers at all.
- Also, you don't need the slow `BigInteger`, just use `long`.
- Storing all numbers in a collection is not necessary, since you only need to keep one number at a time.
- You can of course use `IsPentagonal(n)` (as MT0 does), but I found that simply iterating over the pentagonals is a lot faster. (`Math.Sqrt` is slow)

  ```
  public long Solve045()
  {
      long h = 144L, p = 166L; //given as lower bounds
      long hex, penta = 0L;
      do {
          hex = Hexagonal(h++);
          while (penta < hex) penta = Pentagonal(p++);
      } while (hex != penta);
      return hex;
  }

  private long Hexagonal(long n)
  {
      return n * (2 * n - 1);
  }

  private long Pentagonal(long n)
  {
      return n * (3 * n - 1) / 2;
  }
  ```

You can also inline the 2 methods to keep it all in one place:

```
public long Solve045()
{
    long = 144L, p = 166L; //given as lower bounds
    long hex, penta = 0L;
    Func<long, long> hexagonal = n => n * (2 * n - 1),
                 pentagonal = n => n * (3 * n - 1) / 2;
    do {
        hex = hexagonal(h++);
        while (penta < hex) penta = pentagonal(p++);
    } while (hex != penta);
    return hex;
}
```